# queryResults and multiple if statements following it

Tags: php

In my php code I have the results of the DB displaying and all is good. Now I have added a single line of text that shows the number of rows returned. What I don't like about it is that it shows "There are 1 results" and "There are 5 results", etc. I have made an if statement "if $queryResult = 1" then echo "There is 1 result", and also "if $queryResult > 1" echo "There are xx results", and after that "if $queryResult > 0" echo out all the rows of results.

Right now, this is the code and it works except for the incorrect usage "are" and "results" when there is only 1 result:

```
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "There are ".$queryResult." results.";
if ($queryResult > 0) 
{ // output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ // Display each field of the records.
```

So, I tried this code:

```
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//echo "There are ".$queryResult." results.";
if ($queryResult = 1) 
{
echo "There was ".$queryResult." lesson found.";
}
elseif ($queryResult > 1) 
{
echo "There were ".$queryResult." lessons found.";
}
else ($queryResult > 0) 
{ // output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ // Display each field of the records.
```

and it breaks the page with an error of: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)
I'm sure there's more wrong that just that, I'm sure I'm missing something regarding the first if and elseif statements, but what is it? What am I doing wrong?

I've also enclosed the first if and elseif statements within curly braces but that doesn't work either.

I know that the difference between using "is" and "are" is trivial, but this is being used on a website for people who are learning English as a second language, which means it should be using English correctly. And "There are 1 results" is not good English for new learners to be seeing.

Comment: What is `else ($queryResult > 0) `? This is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your code, one of them being that you were setting your `$queryResult` to `1` here:

```
if ($queryResult = 1)
```

You want:

```
if ($queryResult == 1)
```

However it's easier to condense your code like this:

```
$rsltCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo  $rsltCount === 1 ? "There is 1 result." : "There are ".$rsltCount." results.";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    // Display each field of the records.
}
```

Comment: That isn't what is causing the error they got though.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is

Comment: No it isn't. Look at the error again.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I took the while loop out of the buggy if/else code altogether. Since the question is closed, I won't bother editing my answer to include the `else ($queryResult > 0) ` issue

Comment: Thanks symlink, your corrected code is perfect. Much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone interested in see the working website, here's the url: wiegand.org/CEH.php then click on the button "Lessons".